# Swift 3 - Problems in reusing cell with multiple custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I've got problems when I scroll down in my UITableview. The table shows me cells with old content when the cell is reused.

The Probleme is the following:

Swift wants to reuse an old cell, but doesn't properly clear the old content from the old cell. This leads to cells with old content, although I'm providing new data to the cells.

Architecture of the UITableView if the following:

- Each custom cell has their own identifier
- Each custom cell is separated in an own class

Screenshots of the problem:

**Beginning of the Questionnaire Screen Shot**:

[image: Screen Shot]

**The scrolled down table**:

[image: Screen Shot]

The problem here is the "Handedness"-Cell which is showing the cell number 3 (because of the reuse of the cell), which is not right

**The numberOfSection-Method**

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

**The numberOfRowsInSection-Method**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if(section == 0){
        return questionnaireStructure.count
    } else {
        return 1
    }
}
```

**The cellForRowAt-Method**

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // first section is the normal Questionnaire
    if(indexPath.section == 0){

        // current questionnaireStructure
        let questStruct:QuestionnaireStructure? = questionnaireStructure[indexPath.row]

        // current cell is a "Headline"
        if(questStruct?.elementtype == "elements/headlines"){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeadlineStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! Headline
            cell.headline.text = questStruct?.headline
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.elementtype == "elements/texts"){
            // current cell is a "texts"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextsStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! Texts
            cell.textsLabel.text = questStruct?.text
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.questiontype == "Slider"){
            // currrent cell is a "slider-Question"
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionSliderStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! Slider
            cell.sliderQuestion.text = questStruct?.question
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            let values = (questStruct?.values)!
            let valueArray = values.array as! [Values]
            cell.slider.minimumValue = Float(valueArray[0].min)
            cell.slider.maximumValue = Float(valueArray[0].max)
            let answers = (questStruct?.answers)!
            let answerArray = answers.array as! [Answers]
            cell.minLabel.text = answerArray[0].label
            cell.maxLabel.text = answerArray[1].label

            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.questiontype == "SingleChoice"){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionSingleChoiceStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! SingleChoiceCell
            let radioButtonController = SSRadioButtonsController()
            radioButtonController.delegate = self
            radioButtonController.shouldLetDeSelect = true
            cell.radioButtonController = radioButtonController
            cell.updateCellData(questStruct: questStruct!, indexInTable: indexPath.row)

            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.questiontype == "MultipleChoice"){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionMultipleChoiceStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! MultipleChoiceCell
            cell.multQuestionLabel.text = questStruct?.question
            cell.questStruct = questStruct

            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.questiontype == "YesNoSwitch"){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionYesNoSwitchStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! YesNoSwitch
            cell.yesNoQuestion.text = questStruct?.question
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            return cell
        } else if(questStruct?.questiontype == "TextDate"){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Datepicker", for: indexPath) as! DatePicker
            cell.question.text = questStruct?.question
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionSingleChoiceStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! SingleChoiceCell
            //cell.singleChoiceLabel.text = questStruct?.question
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell
        }

    } else {
        //last section is the save button
        // show the save button when the Questionnaire is loaded
        if(questionnaireStructure.count != 0){
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SaveStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! SaveQuestionnaire
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextsStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! Texts
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
            return cell
        }
    }

}
```

What I checked:

- the data of "questStruct" is providing the latest data
- overriding the "prepareForReuse"-Methode without success

Comment: What is the cell identifier causing the problem?

Comment: *"The problem here is the "Handedness"-Cell ... which is not right"* If that's not right, what is it *supposed* to be showing?

Comment: @Subramanian The cell with the identifier "QuestionSingleChoiceStructureCellID" is causing the problem.

Comment: @Heelow can you update the code of `cell.updateCellData()` method

Comment: @DonMag this is the content of the array
Optional("Date of Birth")
Optional("Gender")
Optional("Handedness")
Optional("Family history of tinnitus complaints")
Optional("If yes")
Optional("Initial onset: When did you first experience your tinnitus?")
Optional("How did you perceive the beginning?")
Optional("Was the initial onset of your tinnitus related to")
Optional("If other") <------ this should be displayed

Comment: "overriding the "prepareForReuse"-Methode without success": Could you show the code of the cell with ID `QuestionSingleChoiceStructureCellID`?

Comment: @DonMag solved the problem :) thank you all guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "QuestionSingleChoiceStructureCellID", for: indexPath) as! SingleChoiceCell
        //cell.singleChoiceLabel.text = questStruct?.question
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
        return cell
    }
```

You need to "reset" the cell in case it's being reused. Options are:

1. write a `reset()` function in the cell, to clear any assigned data and display "default" content, or
2. create an empty `questStruct` and call `cell.updateCellData(questStruct: questStruct!, indexInTable: indexPath.row)`

Option 1. is probably the easiest and most straight-forward.

Comment: `prepareForReuse()` is where to put the `reset()` content.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much!!! :-) This was the bug in the code. I'm so grateful that you helped me

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure the data isn't actually duplicated in the questStruct array?  If that's not the case then all I can think is that it looks like you have two places where a single choice cell is used.  In one of them you set a bunch of data, while in the other one you don't seem to set any data.  I'm talking about that last else statement where you have the part where you set singleChoiceLabel.text except it's commented out.  If that condition gets hit and it's reusing a cell that was configured for the other singleChoiceStructure branch of the if condition then the information will still be filled out from the previous configuration.  It's possible the questionType property of one of your QuestionnaireStructure objects is either spelled incorrectly or just a value you haven't accounted for, which is causing the if statement to hit the else which returns an unconfigured QuestionSingleChoice cell that might still have information from the last time it was used.

Comment: "Are you sure the data isn't actually duplicated in the questStruct array?"

=> Yes I'm absolutely sure. When I print out the questStruct Array it shows the correct content.

Comment: And the questiontype property is spelled exactly correctly including capitalization for every value?  Also I agree with Subramanian: updating the question with the code for updateCellData would be helpful.

Comment: "I'm talking about that last else statement" => How can I avoid the last "else"? The compiler forces me to return a cell in every case

Comment: I don't think you need to avoid the last else statement, though if you wanted to see if that's what is doing it you could return just UITableViewCell() which will return a white cell and make clear what's happening.  Really though you should set a break point there and see if it ever gets hit.  If it does, you know there's most likely a problem with your questionType property

Comment: I think you are right!!!! :-) It gets hits, but I don't know why... That would explain this strange behaviour of the table

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.  Feel free to give me a upvote<3